# Получить данные из Json

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Есть некий Json с массивами внутри него

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 47.5,
        "lat": 42.98
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "clear sky",
            "icon": "01d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 20,
        "feels_like": 15.1,
        "temp_min": 20,
        "temp_max": 20,
        "pressure": 1019,
        "humidity": 52
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7,
        "deg": 20
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 1
    },
    "dt": 1589457073,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 8965,
        "country": "RU",
        "sunrise": 1589419666,
        "sunset": 1589472304
    },
    "timezone": 10800,
    "id": 532096,
    "name": "Makhachkala",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Мне нужно получить данные из

```
 "main": {
        "temp": 20,
        "feels_like": 15.1,
        "temp_min": 20,
        "temp_max": 20,
        "pressure": 1019,
        "humidity": 52
    },
```

Но я не могу получить данные, которые находятся внутри массива.
Остальные данные, такие как `name`,`base`,`cod` я получаю без проблем. Проблема именно в том, что я не могу изъять из массива.

Класс-модель WeatherLocation (как по мне - ошибка в нем, возможно я неправильно прописал `@SerializedName`)

```
public class WeatherLocation {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String locale;

    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private String temperature;

    @SerializedName("humidity")
    @Expose
    private String humidity;


    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public String getTemperature(){
        return temperature;
    }

    public String getHumidity(){
        return humidity;
    }
}
```

Интерфейс

```
public interface WeatherAPI {
    @GET ("weather?q=Makhachkala&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7")
    Call<WeatherLocation> getWeather();
}
```

И сам MainActivity(я специально закоментил 3 поля `tvDescription`,`tvTemperature`,`tvHumidity` так как вылазить исключение `int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference at android.widget.TextView.append`)

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView tvLocation = findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        final TextView tvTemperature = findViewById(R.id.tv_temperature);
        final TextView tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        final TextView tvHumidity = findViewById(R.id.tv_humidity);


        NetworkRequest.getRequest()
                .getWeatherApi()
                .getWeather()
                .enqueue(new Callback<WeatherLocation>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<WeatherLocation> call, Response<WeatherLocation> response) {
                        WeatherLocation weather = response.body();
                        tvLocation.append(weather.getLocale());
                        //tvDescription.append(weather.getDescription());
                        //tvTemperature.append(weather.getTemperature());
                        //tvHumidity.append(weather.getHumidity());


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<WeatherLocation> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Ты задаешь вопрос уже третий раз. Тебе неоднократно сказали сверь модели. У тебя в ответе сервиса одна структура в pojo совсем другая

Comment: @Circassian  я пробовал структуру, которую подсказывал @Ivan. Но после я не могу вызвать метод ```getTemp()``` не сделав его статичным

Comment: Ты можешь залить свой проект на гит? Посмотрю что у тебя там не получается.

Comment: @Circassian https://github.com/idrisov-t/weather

Comment: А где проект? Мне нужно теперь собирать проект самому(

Comment: @Circassian я неправильно загрузил файлы?

Comment: У меня руки еще не дошли собрать проект. Но уже вижу ошибку. Ты сделал класс Main подклассом WeatherLocation и почему-то сделал его статичным. Это боль. Нужно вынести его из этого класса. А в WeatherLocation сделай поле Main main; И переименуй класс Main. В Java так называется точка входа.

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы получить данные из объекта `main` (это не массив, а объект) нужно создать класс для каждого из объектов в json ([POJO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POJO) JAVA классы), и включить эти классы в `WeatherLocation`.

Пример main:

```
 public class Main {

    @SerializedName("temp")
    private Integer temp;
    @SerializedName("feels_like")
    private Double feelsLike;
    @SerializedName("temp_min")
    private Integer tempMin;
    @SerializedName("temp_max")
    private Integer tempMax;
    @SerializedName("pressure")
    private Integer pressure;
    @SerializedName("humidity")
    private Integer humidity;

    ==getters/setters==
}
```

Статья на тему [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/429058/)

Comment: используя ваш совет компилятор предлагает сделать метод ```getTemp()``` статичным, а заодно и саму переменную сделать статичной